# WSL + Visual Studio - can't debug signals properly

Tags: c++, visual-studio, signals, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm debugging this code under Visual Studio (not visual studio code):

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int n = 0;

void handleSignal(int sig) {
//it works from terminal but not from IDE
    printf("Signal received: %d - %d times\n", sig ,++n);
}


int main()
{
    printf("Hi From WSL! - PID: %d\n", getpid());
    auto s = signal(SIGUSR1, handleSignal);

    printf("signal was %d\n", s); // prints 0

    while (n<10) {
        printf("sleeping - %d\n", n);
        sleep(1);    
    }
    printf("Received signals %d timeskill , exiting\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

I run

```bash
kill -10 <pid of process>
```

If I run the code from bash everithing rns fine

```
# output if run from bash:
$ ./LinuxConsoleApplicationWsl.out
Hi From WSL! - PID: 4953
signal was 0
sleeping - 0
sleeping - 0
sleeping - 0
sleeping - 0
sleeping - 0
sleeping - 0
sleeping - 0
sleeping - 0
sleeping - 0
Signal received: 10 - 1 times
sleeping - 1
sleeping - 1
Signal received: 10 - 2 times
sleeping - 2
Signal received: 10 - 3 times
sleeping - 3
Signal received: 10 - 4 times
sleeping - 4
Signal received: 10 - 5 times
sleeping - 5
Signal received: 10 - 6 times
sleeping - 6
Signal received: 10 - 7 times
sleeping - 7
sleeping - 7
sleeping - 7
Signal received: 10 - 8 times
sleeping - 8
Signal received: 10 - 9 times
sleeping - 9
Signal received: 10 - 10 times
Received signals 10 timeskill , exiting
```

(do printfs and at 10th signal sent the app exits) But if I run it from visual studio i got this unhandled exception:

[image: unhandled exception]

What am I missing?

Comment: What happens if you let it continue?

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit When debugging with visual studio once the signal is recived the application exits immediately (it does not continue)

Comment: Fixed updating version to 17.6.5

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own answer:
updating VS to a version 17.6.5 fixed the issue, now the signal is debuggable.

As a note I report that the "exception" is still notified as such but stepping with de debugger works.